# Autofac - Register all derived interfaces and their implementations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

Here are is the structure of the interfaces I want to register:

```
public interface IEventHandler
{
}

public interface IEventHandler<TEvent> : IEventHandler where TEvent : IEvent
{
    void Handle(TEvent @event);
}

public class OnTrackPlayFoundWriteToDebug : IEventHandler<TrackPlayFoundEvent>
{
    public void Handle(TrackPlayFoundEvent @event)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Track found! It's from {@event.TrackPlay.Track.Artist.Name} called {@event.TrackPlay.Track.Name}");
    }
}

public interface IEventPublisher
{
    public void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent: IEvent;
}

public class EventPublisher : IEventPublisher
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IEventHandler> _eventHandlers;

    public EventPublisher(IEnumerable<IEventHandler> eventHandlers)
    {
        _eventHandlers = eventHandlers;
    }

    public void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IEvent
    {
        var eventHandlersForEvent = _eventHandlers.OfType<IEventHandler<TEvent>>();

        foreach (var eventHandler in eventHandlersForEvent)
        {
            eventHandler.Handle(@event);
        }
    }
}
```

So there are multiple issues with registration of this since the only thing that "implements" IEventHandler is another interfaces, but what I want to do is make sure that based on the generic IEventHandler<> interfaces, all classes are registered, so that at the end of the day, the EventPublisher has all of these interfaces injected without any additional work. However I'm unable to get this working. I've tried this registration:

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    //configure auto fac here
    builder.RegisterType<RecentTrackService>().As<IRecentTrackService>();
    
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
       .Where(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEventHandler)))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IEventHandler<>));            

    builder.RegisterType<EventPublisher>().As<IEventPublisher>();
}
```

This doesn't fail when I run it, but the _eventHandlers field in EventPublisher remains empty. How to correctly register this so it works?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEventHandler))`? For `IsAssignableFrom` to return true, the left-hand type should be the base type, and the right-hand type should be the derived type.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. That's what is in the ConfigureContainer method, but it doesn't seem to register these interfaces along with their implementations.

Comment: No, you have `t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEventHandler))`, I'm saying it should be `typeof(IEventHandler).IsAssignableFrom(t)`.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't solve the problem for me. I think the problem is there is no implementation of IEventHandler and I'm not sure how to register classes 2 level above in inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Any suggestions so far? :)